# How to track changes of a form and store in DB

Tags: php, html

I have a form written in PHP/HTML. The form consists of textboxes, dropdowns and checkboxes. What I want to achieve is, I want to track all the changes on the form from textbox, dropdown and checkbox and store it in DB for auditing purposes. I don't need to know the previous data and what has been update but I want to know if user change the textbox1, dropdown and checkbox.

What is the most efficient way to do this on PHP. I've read some triggers in mysql but i want to do it only in PHP.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe show us what you have already? It's quite hard to suggest things without knowing what we have to work with.

Comment: Actually I don't have the code yet for tracking changes but I do only have the form which is a basic form but consist of what ive mentioned. The reason why I ask because I cant think of a best way to achieve this. but i have something in my mind like having such hidden values of all the fields then compare the hidden stored data to the current data of the fields then if it doesn't match then consider it as a change. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your request correctly, when you draw the form you know the values of the fields. You can store a hash of them:

```
<?php
$hash = md5($text . $drop . $check);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="values" value="<?php $hash; ?>" />
```

Then in the process of the submited form you can compare the two values

```
<?php
$previous = $_POST['values'];
$actual = md5($_POST['text'] . $_POST['drop'] . $_POST['check']);
if ($previous !== $actual)
    // you know some values are diferent
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume there isn't going to be ajaxy magic going on in this? If not then maybe something like this?

When user submits the form, take all the values and compare each of them to the values currently held in the database, if they have changed then write to the db, if not do nothing.
In the db have have an on update trigger so that when a row is updated, it copies the old row into another table (archives tables maybe) BEFORE writing the new data. Without knowing what your data looks like or what your table structure is, its hard to supply any more than this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Macjohn solution i've come up to this but i would like to ask what is the efficient way to handle this SQL scenarion. I am sure there is a shortcut to make the code smaller compare on having if statement on every element of the form.

```
if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_input_box1'] !== $newvalueofinputbox1) {

  $data = "Input Box 1 has been changed"'

  $name = $name;
  $date = $datenow;

  $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");  
  $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);
  $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);
  $stm->execute();
}

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_input_box2'] !== $newvalueofinputbox2) {

  $data = "Input Box 2 has been changed"'

  $name = $name;
  $date = $datenow;

  $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");  
  $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);
  $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);
  $stm->execute();
}

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_dropdown1'] !== $newvalueofdropdown1) {

  $data = "Drop Down 1 has been changed"'

  $name = $name;
  $date = $datenow;

  $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");  
  $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);
  $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);
  $stm->execute();
}

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_dropdown2'] !== $newvalueofdropdown2) {

  $data = "Drop Down 2 has been changed"'

  $name = $name;
  $date = $datenow;

  $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");  
  $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);
  $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);
  $stm->execute();
}
```